# Public facing complex business apps on Sharepoint 2010 (or 2007)

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, public

I would like to see some public-facing sites or complex business applications built on top of SHarepoint 2010 (or at least 2007). They can either use Sharepoint's look'n'feel or have a completely custom one.

If they're using Silverlight in heavy doses even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://www.topsharepoint.com/ - they supposedly keep a list of the best SP sites they have come across.

Also MS site has case studies - there are a lot of "internal" ones described so no example or site but some of them have links.
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/customers/Pages/default.aspx?Edition=SharePoint%202010

(That is only the 2010 page but you can get to the 2007 ones as well).

Comment: I guess Microsoft's list is mostly just deployments + administration sites in companies' intra/extranets...

Comment: @Robert - yeah MS you have stumble on the public ones, they are mixed in there though. I vaguely remember a couple local govt sites that they profiled that were public (wish they had a better search for case studies).

Answer (score 0):

Check [academic](http://www.alba.edu.gr/Pages/Default.aspx) site, it's made with Sharepoint 2007. Their [application system](https://applications.alba.edu.gr/), and [career portal](http://community.alba.edu.gr/careers/Pages/default.aspx) also runs on Sharepoint as well as the their academic intranet, which creates course sites with student forums, asignments etc. using enrollment data from their CRM.